# How to send an array to server with axios

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm using `axios` and my backend is laravel/php.
I should send an `form-data` like this:

```
national_id:123
social_media[0][social_id]:1
social_media[0][username]:myuser
```

my data:

```
       var social_media = []

        let newSocial = {
            "social_id": 1,
            "username": myuser
        }            
        social_media.push(newSocial)

    const data = {
        "national_id": national_id,
        "social_media": social_media,
        "image":image
    }
```

my axios post:

```
  updateUser = (data) => {
    const headers = {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
    let formData = new FormData();
    for ( var key in data ) {
        formData.append(key, data[key]);
    }

    return this.init(headers).post("/users/"+data.user_id, formData);
  };
```

but I got this error:

```
errors: {social_media: ["The social media must be an array."]}
message: "The given data was invalid."
```

my network tab:

```
national_id: 123
social_media: [object Object]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing the code used by the server to decode the data.

However, the first thing I'd try, assuming no access to server code, is encoding the array as a JSON string:

change this:

```
  const data = {
        "national_id": national_id,
        "social_media": social_media,
        "image":image
    }
```

to this:

```
  const data = {
        "national_id": national_id,
        "social_media": JSON.stringify(social_media),
        "image":image
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sending an array, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append, you can send multiple values with the same name:

```js
formData.append('userpic[]', myFileInput.files[0], 'chris1.jpg');
formData.append('userpic[]', myFileInput.files[1], 'chris2.jpg');
```

Also, you might need to stringify the objects with `JSON.stringify`.

So for your case, you can do something like this

```js
let formData = new FormData();
for (var key in data) {
  if (Array.isArray(data[key])) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data[key].length; i++) {
      formData.append(`${key}[]`, JSON.stringify(data[key][i]));
    }
  } else {
    formData.append(key, data[key]);
  }
}
```